# Regex Pattern duda java

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public class getTag2Html {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        String tag = "<p>";

                URL web = new URL("http://www.insalfonscostafreda.cat/web/");
        //comprobar que hi hagi dos paràmetres a l'entrada

                System.out.println("Busquem a : "+web + " l'etiqueta p");
            // patró de cerca regexp
            String pattern = "<" + tag + ".*\\/?>";

            //Iniciem la connexió
        web.openConnection();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(web.openStream()));

        File f = new File("eac2.xml");
        BufferedWriter bw;
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

            if(inputLine.contains("<p>")) {

                System.out.println(inputLine);
                bw.write(inputLine + "\n");
            }
        }
        bw.close();
        in.close(); 
    }
}
```

No entiendo como usar la parte:

```
String pattern = "<" + tag + ".*\\/?>";
```

El programa me funciona perfectamente pero tengo que usar import

```
java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

El tema es necesito darle dos argumentos ( pagina web y por ejemplo < p > ). 
y mostrarme en pantalla la información.

Lo hace perfectamente, pero no sé como modificarlo para que sea usando regex.

Ahora mismo el programa muestra la pagina web que le he dado por argumento pero solo muestra los datos que estan en < p >.

Pero el enunciado me incluye la parte de codigo String pattern = "<" + tag + ".*\/?>"; que no sé como utilizar en mi programa.

podéis ayudarme?

gracias

Comment: deberias editar la pregunta y especificar que es lo que quieres hacer realmente, de otra forma solo podemos inferir de acuerdo al codigo. ¿Que es lo que hace perfectamente?

Comment: acabo de editar la pregunta. Pero lo que me hace bien es mostrarme la pagina web y los datos de < p >. Lo que no entiendo es que significa el String pattern y como usarlo.

Comment: es decir necesito incluirlo en mi programa si o si. Pero no sé para que sirve ni como hacerlo.

Comment: Ok, tienes que usar el patron especificado para resolver un problema. Pero ¿Cual es el problema? Si quieres preguntar como usar un patron de expresion regular en java para encontrar coincidencias es una pregunta valida, pero da la impresion que quieres replicar el comportamiento de tu programa (que tampoco parece ser correcto) usando el patron y eso es otra pregunta que requiere que clarifiques.

Comment: Por ejemplo, yo podria pensar que quieres obtener el **contenido** de cualquier tag html pasado por parametro y eso no es algo que estes logrando con ese codigo porque solo analizas lineas que contengan `<p>` y no te interesa ver donde cierra ese `</p>`

Comment: es decir el programa me muestra una pagina web y de dentro de esta pagina solo los < p > que es lo que necesito que muestre. Pero entiendo como dices que necesito usar el patron para hacer la busqueda más exacta que es lo que me faltaría. No sé explicarlo 100% por que no sé para que sirve el string pattern. Pero la idea es incluirlo en mi programa. Aunque como dices no sé si es lo correcto o habría que hacerlo de nuevo. Pero me muestra la página y lo que quiero así que entiendo que mal no lo tengo..

Comment: es decir necesito que me muetre del html solo los <p>. y ahora mismo los muestra. No necesito nada más de información solo los <p> de la página.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75210/discussion-between-klaimmore-and-montse-mkd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En resumen de lo que entendi en el chat, lo que se solicita es poco comun:

- Leer linea a linea el contenido html de la URL pasada por parametro
- Por cada linea:

  - Si existe un match con la expresion regular `<TAG.*\\/?>` donde `TAG` puede ser cualquier tag html pasado por parametro, entonces:
  - Imprimir la linea completa donde ocurre dicho match.

El error que estas cometiendo para utilizar la expresion regular, es pensar que TAG puede ser `<p>` en lugar de solo `p`, la expresion ya contiene los simbolos `<` y `>`, por lo que TAG solo debe ser el nombre del tag.

Luego, para resolver algo asi efectivamente puedes utilizar `Pattern` y `Matcher`, estas clases se utilizan de la siguiente forma:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expresion);
```

Donde expresion es la expresion regular a utilizar como `String` de java. Solo compilas la expresion 1 vez, dado que la expresion es una sola.

Luego, para encontrar coincidencias en un texto se utiliza:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);
```

Con eso puedes consultar al matcher por las coincidencias en cada linea, de la siguiente forma:

- `matcher.matches()`: retorna `true` si el texto por completo cumple con la expresion regular.
- `matcher.find()`: retorna `true` si encuentra **alguna** coincidencia en el texto.

Ocurren mas cosas cuando invocas a esos metodos, pero para tu problema en particular basta con eso.

Luego, en lugar de utilizar:

```
if(inputLine.contains("<p>")) { ... }
```

Utiliza:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputLine);
if(matcher.find()) { ... }
```

---

Ahora bien, ¿Es necesario usar Pattern y Matcher para algo simple como eso?

La respuesta es no. Pero si es mas eficiente que utilizar por ejemplo:

```
if(inputLine.matches(".*<TAG.*\\/?>.*")){ ... }
```

Dado que lo anterior requiere que se compile la expresion regular en cada linea.

Comment: gracias por la explicación tan detallada! :) lo pruebo en un rato y te digo. pero ya entiendo para que usar el match  y el pattern algo que hasta ahora no entendía. gracias!!